# HOCON conditional substitution with surrounding text

Tags: java, substitution, playback, hocon

I have no way currently to test this syntax myself, thus the question:

Will substitution/overriding of a value still happen if it's surrounded by text?

For example, I know that:

`foo.baseUrl = "http://foo:1234/"
foo.baseUrl = ${?FOO_BASE_URL}`

will overwrite `foo.baseURL` if the ENV var `FOO_BASE_URL` exists.

What happens here?

`foo.baseUrl = "http://foo:1234/"
foo.baseUrl = "http://${?FOO_BASE_URL}:1234/"`

does the override still happen if the ENV var exists?
does putting it within a string negate this?

Comment: I RTFM, thanks, otherwise I wouldn't be asking :-) Is there some particular portion that I missed? @Leo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ran a quick test, and the second value will replace the first, missing the middle part. So if `FOO_BASE_URL` is not defined, and `application.conf` contains the following (note omission of `"` in the second line, variable substitution is not performed within double quotes):

```
foo.baseUrl = "http://foo:1234/"
foo.baseUrl = http://${?FOO_BASE_URL}:1234/
foo.baseUrl = ${?FOO_BASE_URL}
```

The value of `foo.baseUrl` will be `http://:1234/`. The not-found variable is considered an empty string in the second line. The relevant quote from the [Substitution](https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#substitutions) section of the docs:

> If a substitution with the `${?foo}` syntax is undefined:
>
> - if it is the value of an object field then the field should not be created. If the field would have overridden a previously-set value for the same field, then the previous value remains.
> - if it is an array element then the element should not be added.
> - if it is part of a value concatenation with another string then it should become an empty string; if part of a value concatenation with an object or array it should become an empty object or array.
> - `foo : ${?bar}` would avoid creating field `foo` if `bar` is undefined. `foo : ${?bar}${?baz}` would also avoid creating the field if *both* `bar` and `baz` are undefined.